# Pug Templating iterate through multiple arrays in JSON data object?

Tags: json, loops, iteration, pug

I am new to pug. I am using JSON files to store my data used in the pug file. This is my data structure:

```
{
  "nav": {
     "titles": [
      "location",
      "reservations",
      "accomodations",
      "amenities"
    ],
    "icons": [
      "img/sprite.svg#icon-location2",
      "img/sprite.svg#icon-book",
      "img/sprite.svg#icon-key",
      "img/sprite.svg#icon-glass"
    ]
  }
}
```

I know how to loop through a single array in the JSON. My problem is how to pull data into the template for more then one item off the data object. For instance I want to loop to get both the titles and the icons from my `nav.json` file. My pug file looks like this

```
li(class="top-nav__item")
  a(class="top-nav__link")
    svg(class="top-nav__icon")
      use(xlink:href=icon)
        span=title
```

I've tried nesting the loops

```
each title in nav.titles
  each icon in nav.icons
```

and using logical operators

```
each title in nav.titles && each icon in nav.icons
```

and pulling off the object directly like

```
each n in nav
```

None of those worked. How do I do this in pug? Should I set my data up a differently to be able to do this? Or is there a different way to loop through and grab the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` and `icon` correspond and should be grouped together. If your data looked like this, you'd have an easier time of it:

```
{
  "nav": [{
    "title": "location",
    "icon": "img/sprite.svg#icon-location2"
  }, {
    "title": "reservations",
    "icon": "img/sprite.svg#icon-book"
  }, {
    "title": "accommodations",
    "icon": "img/sprite.svg#icon-key"
  }, {
    "title": "amenities",
    "icon": "img/sprite.svg#icon-glass"
  }]
}
```

Alternatively, you could `each i in [0, 1, 2, 3]` and use the `i` value to pull matching titles and icons out of their respective arrays. But relying on data lining up across multiple arrays is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you! @dmfay That worked. I am iterating over the object w/ each i in nav and assigning the values i.titles i.icons.